# How to extract specific folder only from zip via 7z CLI?

Tags: command-line-interface, 7zip

I'm trying to automate part of my workflow that includes extracting specific files/folders from a couple archives and then put together into a single folder. Most of the contents of these I would like to ignore and instead of *excluding* I'd prefer to *include* what I'm interested by root folder names.

The structure of the archive look something like this:

```
archive.zip
├── folder_one
│   └── subfolder_one.txt
│       ├──
│       ├── file_one.txt
│       ├── file_two.txt
│       └── ...
├── folder_two
├── folder_three
└── ...
```

And from this I would like to extract everything to a destination folder that looks like this:

```
destination_folder
└── subfolder_one.txt
    ├──
    ├── file_one.txt
    ├── file_two.txt
    └── ...
```

Assuming I'm already in the same directory as the archive I can extract the zip with:

```
7z x archive.zip -oC:/temp/destination_folder
```

But this results in the extracted folder having the same structure as it originally did in the archive as well as extracting unwanted folders:

```
destination_folder
├── folder_one
│   └── subfolder_one.txt
│       ├──
│       ├── file_one.txt
│       ├── file_two.txt
│       └── ...
├── folder_two
├── folder_three
└── ...
```

#### Question:

How would I alter the command to extract the selected folder only, making the selected folder as without root folders?